# is there any thing like ELMAH axd for log4net to monitor logs?

Tags: asp.net, log4net, elmah

is there any component or thing like **ELMAH axd** file available for **log4net** ?

Comment: I donot think log4net provides a UI.

Comment: Take a look at reflect insight http://insightextensions.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I donot think log4net provides a UI.

But you can use various log4net Viewer like:

**1** [LogViewer for Log4Net](http://yourlog4netviewer.codeplex.com/)

LogViewer is a WPF application allowing to view Log4Net log files.
Logs must be in Xml (just need a few lines in your application config file to configure it to use this format).
Search, log merging, filtering are already supported but the project is open for new enhancements.

**2** [YALV!](http://yalv.codeplex.com/)

YALV! is a log viewer for Log4Net that allow to compare multiple logs file simultaneously; include features like merging, filtering, open most recently used files, items sorting.

**3** [LOG4VIEW](http://www.log4view.com/home/)

LOG4VIEW is the powerful log viewer for log4net, NLog and log4j

Comment: Log4View link is broken... http://www.log4view.com/